# Trying to code a fighting function for class and need help getting the attributes from the class into the separate fight function

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Player(Entity):

    def __init__(self, name, health, attack, speed, armor):
        #Call Entity constructor
        super().__init__(name, health, attack, speed)
        self.__armor = armor
```

trying to get the speed from this class and

```
class Enemy(Entity):

    def __init__(self, name, health, attack, speed, special):
        #Call Entity constructor
        super().__init__(name, health, attack, speed)
        #new attributes
        self.__special = special
```

so that I can use them in

```
def fight():

    result = ""
    fighting = True
    playerTurn = True
    playerRun = False

    createEnemy()
    main()

    if Player(self.speed) >= Enemy(self.speed):
        playerTurn = True
    else:
        playerTurn = False
```

in order to find out whether the player or the enemy goes first. I have tried multiple ways to try and get the attribute out but haven't gotten any results, anyone have any answers? if you do nothing to complicated just started learning python.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with the attributes of a class, it's usually necessary to create an instance of that class, to represent the specific entity that is acting/being acted upon.  This is the difference between the concept of cars (the class) and *your* physical car (the instance).

Generally, you create instances of a class by calling the class itself (which will call your `__init__` method, as well as some other stuff)

```
def fight():
    result = ""
    fighting = True
    playerTurn = True
    playerRun = False
    player = Player("Jim", 1, 2, 3, 4)

    enemy = createEnemy()  # This function should return an Enemy object 
    main()

    if player.speed >= enemy.speed:
        playerTurn = True
    else:
        playerTurn = False
```

Comment: I tried that and got: File "E:\Programming\Final Project\Final Project Classes.py", line 101, in fight
    if player.speed >= enemy.speed:
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'speed'

Comment: What's going on in your `Entity` class?  You're passing `Entity.__init__` a speed value.

Comment: I only created Entity because we needed to include inheritance into the project

Comment: So add inheritance.  Put a `self.speed = speed` line in the `__init__` method.  You should probably include on for each of the other values as well.